# XPath Check that every node has the expected value

Tags: xml, xpath

Given the following XML:

```
<root>
    <a>
        <b>Correct</b>
    </a>
    <a>
        <b>Correct</b>
    </a>
    <a>
        <b>Oh no!</b>
    </a>
</root>
```

I need a XPath query, that will ensure that every `<b>`-Node has the value "Correct".
Do you have any ideas? Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: (note that to get angle brackets to appear correctly they *must* be formatted-as-code, either in back ticks or with a four-space indent. The `{}` button in the editor will do the right thing to selected text, to format it as code)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you mean "select all correct nodes", you can use `/root/a/b[text() = 'Correct']` which will return a node set.

If you mean "check whether all nodes are correct" you can use `every $i in /root/a/b/text() satisfies $i = 'Correct'` which will return a boolean.

Comment: I meant the second option. Sorry for may being imprecise. It worked like a charm!

Comment: Note that the every ... satisfies thingy is XPath 2 only, though. An XPath 1 solution could be to check whether /root/a/b[text() != 'Correct'] returns anything.

Comment: It's OK, I used it with soapUI Pro (Version 4) and it seems to work with XPath 2.

Answer (score 1):

```
/root/a/b[normalize-space(.) != 'Correct']
```

Comment: This will return any `b` element that = 'Correct', but it won't tell you if there are any `b` elements that don't = 'Correct'. I think you would want `/root/a/b[normalize-space(.) != 'Correct']` instead.